# Patterns and trends for startup names

Tags: english, onomastics

Does anyone have any stats, research papers, etc. surrounding trends for startup naming.

It seems quote popular to, for example: remove vowels from words, start the company name with a lower-case letter, etc. and I am wondering if anyone has done analysis on said trends.

I am familiar with this informative article on the subject: https://techcrunch.com/2018/02/10/startups-are-still-making-weird-name-choices/.

Comment: The way I thought of approaching this is to take data from domain listings or Crunchbase or the app marketplaces, and train a char-level model to 1) suggest names given other params 2) valuate new names.

Comment: This topic is not a 'core' linguistics research topic, but I don't think it really falls into usage questions either. The OP is asking for descriptive data about startup names, not asking for tips about creating startup names or whatever.